# pl/sql forward multiple emails with attachments as .msg files like outlook

Tags: java, oracle, email, plsql

I am using Oracle 11g and use UTL_SMTP (successfully) to send emails with attachments from our database.

I break apart/store incoming emails into two tables:

```
-  email_in (columns: from, to, dttm, subject, body (as clob) etc.)

-  email_in_attachments .(columns: filename, file type, data (as blob) etc.).
```

However, what I would like to do is mimic MS Outlook where you can select multiple emails and forward them as attachments (as a message file .msg).

I'm thinking that I would have to recreate/reassemble the incoming email from the two tables above and then save it as a message file in a third table as a blob in order to forward it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clue:
Email messages with attachments are not some text + discrete files.

Think of it as one continuous file, where each section is identified by a header to indicate each of these parts.  The helper methods you may have used simply parse through the message and deliver it's content in separated blocks as identified by each section's header.

If others want to drop other clues or open up the discussion to specific examples, I'll leave this response as a "community wiki".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand what you are saying; however, I am hoping that an example exists somewhere. I have googled "UTL_SMTP how to forward multiple emails" and other variations which have not returned any results. in fact my question on stackflow is number one on google when you serach for that phrase.